# Python get valid date format from date string

Tags: python, datetime

Is there a way to *guess* datetime format of a given string in python?

e.g. desired usage would be:

```py
> guess_format('2020-02-24 07:22')
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```

There's [dateutil](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil) project which automates datetime string conversion to valid `Datetime` objects:

```py
> from dateutil.parser import parse
> parse('2020-02-24 07:22')
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 24, 7, 22)
```

but can it produce valid formatting strings?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible at all. You need some magic tricks to guess format of `'10/11/09'`. It can be done if you'll input large list with examples of dates listed in same format, but even this won't give you 100% guarantee.

Comment: If you can guess the datetime (via `dateutil`) then you could infer a format too, right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this module, but if it fits your requirements you can trace over function chain and find function where it generates format (or whatever it uses) and try to override.

Comment: I've already looked into the source of `dateutil` but the parser logic is 2000 lines long and quite difficult to follow though I don't believe it exposes formatting anywhere :(

Comment: maybe [this](https://pypi.org/project/py-dateinfer/) is what you are looking for

Comment: I doubt it is predictable with reasonable accuracy, for example: `parse('10-12-24 07:22')` gives `datetime.datetime(2024, 10, 12, 7, 22)`. Only if you have strings that you know will follow a particular convention for `y-m-d` order, you can write something on your own, given you put checks for `length`, 'max_value` of each field. Otherwise things like `datetime.datetime.strptime('020202', format)` is pretty much unpredictable.

Comment: This is not possible in a perfect manner. It would be best to create a tuple/list of the string and then detect the format. But confusion will be in day-month since US writes month-day instead. Also, in hour seconds format, how do you know thats not minutes:seconds? Can this situation be true? If yes then handle it.

Comment: I understand your concerns that "this is not possible to be perfect" but that's unrelated to the question - I've specifically put emhpasis on __guess__ in my question.

Comment: @Granitosaurus, you don't need to follow all 2000 lines manually, you can [trace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html) it and find needed function ;)

Comment: @luigigi Thanks, this does seem to be step in a right direction but the package is unmaintained and a bit dated (last commit 6 years ago) but it does work to some extend! Could you add this as an answer? Here's my attempt: https://gist.github.com/Granitosaurus/fdbaac3fe2703e1af5e0beb6148bec30

Comment: @Granitosaurus done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [pydateinfer](https://pypi.org/project/py-dateinfer/) package provides the possibility to infer the datetime format string of a given date string.

Example:

```
>>> import dateinfer
>>> dateinfer.infer(['Mon Jan 13 09:52:52 MST 2014', 'Tue Jan 21 15:30:00 EST 2014'])
'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

Comment: It should be noted that `dateinfer` isn't very smart and need a big set of samples but for my case I have several thousand samples and it did reasonably well!